# Angular UI-Router resetting querystring params on reload

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I currently have a state that looks like this:

```
.state('test-event-list', {
    parent: 'private',
    url: '/test-events?search&sortc&sortd&pagesize&page&select&status',
    reloadOnSearch: false,
    views: {
        'view@body': {
            templateUrl: 'app/config-test/test-event/list.html',
            controller: require('./config-test/test-event/list')
        }
    },
    data: {
        auth: true
    }
})
```

I am using $location.search() to set the different parameters such as sorting, list size and list page in the querystring.

So for example, the URL could look like this:

```
/test-events?pagesize=25&page=1
```

I have a menu that has the following link to select the tests event list:

```
<a ui-sref="test-event-list" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true, inherit: false}">Tests</a>
```

While in the state "test-event-list", clicking this link, does partly what I want: reset the list's parameters and reload the page. But what it's not doing is remove the params from the query string.

**How could I go about removing "?pagesize=25&page=1" from the URL?**

The inherit flag provided by ui-router doesn't seem to be doing much. I am using the latest version of ui-router (0.2.15).

Comment: Could you provide a plunker with this behaviour ? I'd really like to see how we can solve this.

Comment: Did you try to set them to null ?  ui-sref="test-event-list({pagesize : null, page : null})" This may work.

Comment: @Okazari I'd rather not set them individually because if the params get changed, I would have to go back and redo all the menu items. I'll see if I can get a plunker up for ya

Comment: that's true, that's wasn't a good idea for code maintainability

Comment: @Okazari I tried setting them to null and it didn't work. I think I tried that as well at some point. Since they are querystring params and not state params that wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: According to some (non-official) documentation, this should work with querystrings http://benfoster.io/blog/ui-router-optional-parameters . But nvm let's try some other things on a plunker.

Comment: It appears that reloadOnSearch: false breaks things, as described in this issue  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/677

Answer (score 7):

You could try to go:

```
<a ui-sref="test-event-list({})" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true, inherit: false}">Tests</a>
```

because query strings parameters are not mandatory

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion rave but I have already tried that and no dice sadly. The querystring is not removed from the URL.

Comment: Thanks rave, this actually did work for me. angular v1.3.14 + ui-router v0.2.15

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue where I just wanted to remove the query from the end of the URL. I was able to remove the query by passing an empty string for each param. It would look something like this for you.

```
<a ui-sref="test-event-list({ pagesize: '', page: '' })">Tests</a>
```

For me is was a little different. I didn't need to pass in the current routes name.

```
<a ui-sref="{ date: '' }">all logs</a>
```